# Error Importe Excel With OpenRowSet

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to import data from an Excel file on my disk `C:` but when I execute the query

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;Database=C:\Hola.xlsx', 'SELECT * FROM [Ripley$]')
```

I get this error

> Msg 7308, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' cannot be used for distributed queries because the provider is configured to run in single-threaded apartment mode

I tried this

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO

EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

but it does not work. Somebody could help me please?

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and office 2010

Comment: What's the query you're using?

Comment: im using this query

SELECT *
FROM   OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
       'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;Database=C:\Hola.xlsx',
       'SELECT * FROM [Ripley$]')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SELECT` statement inside your connection string is not needed, you can remove it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;Database=C:\Hola.xlsx', [Ripley$]')
```

You may also not need the `Xml` portion (but I'm not sure if that would cause an error):

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;Database=C:\Hola.xlsx', [Ripley$]')
```

Comment: i see well now i have other question about it i was searching and i found this http://www.maxxxie.net/2012/07/01/the-joys-of-importing-excel-data-into-sql-2008-r2/ in that url i need to install a services from microsoft access to execute correctly my query. I talked about this with my boss but he doesnt want install it i have other way to to this?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, you need to install services and have admin priveleges for this functionality.  Best alternative is to just import the excel files via the import/export wizard in SSMS, or use SSIS to handle the import.